# AWS lambda function: unexpected token

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function. The handler function is empty (commeneted out for troubleshooting purpose)
when I hit test I get an error message as follows:

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
  "errorMessage": "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'",
    "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1084:17)",
    "    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1119:21)",
    "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:23)",
    "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:1"
  ]
}
```

I did not experience the error earlier but suddenly it changed. I did not change the configuration.
What shall I do to get rid of the error message?

EDITED: my code look like the following, a simple handler function for database access:

```
import mysql from 'mysql2/promise';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk'; 

export const handler = async (event) => {

    try {
        // Database configuration using environment variables
        const dbConfig = {
            host: process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME,
            user: process.env.RDS_USERNAME,
            database: process.env.RDS_DATABASE,
            password: process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
            port: 3306, // Default MySQL port
        };

        // Create a connection pool
        const pool = await mysql.createPool(dbConfig);
        // Use the pool to query the database
        const [rows, fields] = await pool.execute('SELECT * FROM your_table');
        // Process the result as needed
        const result = rows.map(row => /* Process each row */);
    
         const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: "OK"
        };
    // Return the response constant
    return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
};
```

Comment: You seem to have other code that's not shown that is causing the parsing error. Without seeing that code, it's going to be difficult to help.

Comment: Please Edit your Question and include the code that is causing this error.